# ошибка при компиляции проекта на c#

Tags: c#, компиляция

установил я компилятор из этого топика: https://medium.com/@hudsonmendes/build-net-4-5-on-linux-in-5-minutes-and-see-what-it-is-like-848ea45fc667
и при команде в консоль:
xbuild (Проект).sln(не спрашивайте зачем я через консоль компилирую, мне надо()

выводит следующую ошибку:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9): error MSB4062: невозможно загрузить задачу "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.Csc" из сборки C:\Users\User\Desktop\Bots\C#\Telegram\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.3.8.0\build\..\tools\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll. Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл. Проверьте правильность объявления <UsingTask> и доступность сборки со всеми ее зависимостями.
```

в гугле говорят, что удаление этого пакета решает проблему, но не в моем случае. если я удалю этот пакет, то будет следующее:

```
modules\Send.cs(111,25): error CS1056: Непредусмотренный символ "$"

modules\Send.cs(112,25): error CS1056: Непредусмотренный символ "$"

modules\Send.cs(113,25): error CS1056: Непредусмотренный символ "$"

modules\Send.cs(114,25): error CS1056: Непредусмотренный символ "$"

modules\Send.cs(115,25): error CS1056: Непредусмотренный символ "$"

modules\Send.cs(116,25): error CS1056: Непредусмотренный символ "$"

modules\Send.cs(117,25): error CS1056: Непредусмотренный символ "$"

modules\Send.cs(118,25): error CS1056: Непредусмотренный символ "$"

modules\Send.cs(119,25): error CS1056: Непредусмотренный символ "$"
```

что делать в таком случае?

Comment: `Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core,` не двусмысленно намекает... А зачем вам под Linuxом собирать проект, который рассчитан на сборку под виндой? Настоящие герои не ищут легких путей что-ли?

Comment: @Bulson я хочу создать телеграмм бота который при команде /build компилировал проект и отправлял, все уже готово кроме компиляции. хостинг на линуксе, хост на виндовс обойдется в 600р как минимум

Comment: Создайте под линуксом новый .Net 5 проект, и скопируйте в него все ваши наработки и скомпилируйте. Чего сложного то? У вас же там не бог весть какой сложный код. Все должно получится.

Comment: @Bulson ну вообще)) у меня код примерно на 10к строк, мб больше

Comment: И что? Copy/Paste работает и в линуксе.

Comment: @Bulson так у этих фреймворков же не одинаковые библиотеки и модули

Comment: А какие у вас такие библиотеки? Большинство уже успешно поддерживают .Net Standart 2.0.

Comment: Возьмите azure dev ops, там бесплатные часы билд агента есть

Comment: @Bulson перенес весь проект на .net core 5... результат...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(63,5): error NETSDK1100: Windows is required to build Windows desktop applications. [/root/Bot/Telegramr/localhost121/localhost121.csproj]

Comment: Ничего не понятно, если вам надо собирать на Linux, почему в ошибке "C:\Windows\..."? Вы хотите собирать на Linux приложение для Windows? Это невозможно с помощью .NET 5, используйте mono xbuild, как и написано в статье по ссылке.